# jQuery popup window scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a popup using jQuery `.dialog` function. The dialog is popping up properly and also closes when hitting close button. I have a problem with the position of the dialog. It opens on the middle of the window, but then it does not scroll down when the user scrolls down.

I'm calling the popup in this way:

```
function onClick(id, name, state, func){
    $("#popup").dialog('open');
    $("#popup").dialog('option', 'title', name);
    $("#popup").html('<div id="content"><p>variables used in here</p></div>');
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way, I'm not very familiar with web development. The function is fired but I'm not happy with the position of the popup. I tried positioning it using css `position, margin` properties, but without any success.

Do I have to remember something or how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use position:fixed on the dialog box and you can place it wherever you so choose.

Comment: @mhodges Unfortunately the dialog disappears when using fixed or absolute positioning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:fixed` to the dialog, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/6662/

I made the body 1000px height so you can see how it behaves when scrolling.

This will keep the dialog where it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the default position of the dialog is `relative`. If I change this to `fixed`, the dialog disappears. I added all those properties in your example to my dialog and set `position:fixed;` to it. But it disappears. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to set the z-index of the dialog. I'm assuming it's getting hidden because it's behind other content. Also make sure to set a top and left offset for the dialog to make sure it's within the screen boundaries

Comment: If I hover over the element in chrome firebug it shows me it's above the top. It also has some `top` style like `-3864.34px` by default...

Comment: And if I remove those default top stylings, it's below the bottom of the page :/

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've set the fixed positioning to the existing class instead of the class I declared in `dialogClass`. Works like a charm. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI used inline `position: absolute`.
you should add `position: fixed !important;` to resolve it.

Comment: check z-index and pay attention to parent position and z-index.